# Commit a mysql docker image does not embed a new database

Tags: docker

If I create a database in a mysql container and commit it as a new image. The new image does not persit the database. Here is the scenario

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql
docker exec -it some-mysql bash
root@e756b3aa719b:/# mysql -uroot -pmy-secret-pw 

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database michael;

mysql> show databases;         
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| michael            |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
root@e756b3aa719b:/# exit
exit
```

Then I commit this container as an image

```
docker commit 486932c6d7e7 bdd/myproj:1.0
```

If I create a container from this image the database is not here

```
docker run --name newbdd -e  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mybdd/myproj:1.0
docker exec -it newbdd bash
root@004f86506ebf:/# mysql -uroot -pmy-secret-pw
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

What's really weird is that the mysql client kept the history of the command "create database michael" but the server does not keep the database michael.

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

Working as intended.    Data inside a container is not typically a best practice.   The mysql base image specifies the data directory as a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) which does not persist.

Comment: You're right if I read the dockerfile /var/lib/mysql is a volume. In the link you provide : _Changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an image_